# What means #some-number in Rails log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I have log file in Rails 4.

Here is string.

`I, [2014-09-30T19:16:23.434591 #6942]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 1176ms (ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)`

What means number after DATETIME? `#6942`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is process id: `PID`

Log format: `SeverityID, [DateTime #pid] SeverityLabel -- ProgName: message`

Log sample: `I, [1999-03-03T02:34:24.895701 #19074]  INFO -- Main: info.`

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-Format